# Calculating expection of number of draws necessary to capture $m$ marked animals

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

I'm working on the following problem, but I'm stuck and I hope anyone can provide some help:

> A population of $N$ animals has had a certain number $a$ of its members captured, marked and then released. Show that the probability $p_n$ that it is necessary to capture $n$ animals in order to obtain $m$ which have been marked is $$p_n=  \frac{a}{N}\binom{a-1}{m-1}\binom{N-a}{n-m}\left/\binom{N-1}{n-1}\right.,$$ where $m \leq n \leq N-a+m$. Hence, show that $$\frac{a}{N}\binom{a-1}{m-1}\frac{(N-a)!}{(N-1)!}\sum_{n=m}^{N-a+m}\frac{(n-1)!(N-n)!}{(n-m)!(N-a+m-n)!}=1,$$ and that the expectation of $n$ is $\frac{N+1}{a+1}m$.

Well, I was able to do every step, but I'm stuck at what to do to show that $\mathbb{E}(n)=\frac{N+1}{a+1}m$. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the  probabilities when  we multiply them  recursively we  get two
shuffled         contributions         $a^{\underline{m}}$         and
$(N-a)^{\underline{n-m}}$ in the  numerator and $N^{\underline{n}}$ in
the denominator.  The last item  must be a  marked animal and  for the
animals which came before that we may choose their positions according
to ${n-1\choose m-1}.$ We thus get for the probabilities

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{P}[X=n] = \frac{a^{\underline{m}} (N-a)^{\underline{n-m}}}
{N^{\underline{n}}} {n-1\choose m-1}.}$$

Working to convert this into binomial coefficients we get

$$\mathrm{P}[X=n] =
m! \times {a\choose m} \times (n-m)! \times {N-a\choose n-m}
\times {N\choose n}^{-1} \frac{1}{n!} \times {n-1\choose m-1}
\\ = m! \times {a\choose m} \times (n-m)! \times {N-a\choose n-m}
\times {N\choose n}^{-1} \frac{1}{n!} \times \frac{m}{n} {n\choose m}
\\ = \frac{m}{n} {a\choose m} {N-a\choose n-m}
{N\choose n}^{-1}.$$

To verify that  this is a probability distribution we  observe that we
must draw  at least $m$ animals  (initial sequence all marked)  and at
most $N-a+m$ animals (non-marked individuals come first).

We get for the probabilities

$$m {a\choose m}
\sum_{n=m}^{N-a+m} {N-a\choose n-m}
\frac{1}{n} {N\choose n}^{-1}
= m {a\choose m}
\sum_{n=0}^{N-a} {N-a\choose n}
\frac{1}{n+m} {N\choose n+m}^{-1}
\\ = m {a\choose m}
\sum_{n=0}^{N-a} {N-a\choose n}
\mathrm{B}(n+m, N-n-m+1)
\\ = m {a\choose m}
\sum_{n=0}^{N-a} {N-a\choose n}
\int_0^1 t^{n+m-1} (1-t)^{N-n-m} \; dt
\\ = m {a\choose m}
\int_0^1 t^{m-1} (1-t)^{N-m}
\sum_{n=0}^{N-a} {N-a\choose n} \frac{t^n}{(1-t)^n}
\; dt
\\ = m {a\choose m}
\int_0^1 t^{m-1} (1-t)^{N-m}
\left(1+\frac{t}{1-t}\right)^{N-a}
\; dt
\\ = m {a\choose m}
\int_0^1 t^{m-1} (1-t)^{a-m}
\; dt
= m {a\choose m} \mathrm{B}(m, a-m+1)
\\ = m {a\choose m} \frac{1}{m} {a\choose m}^{-1} = 1.$$

Now for the expectation we re-use this same computation, getting

$$m + m {a\choose m}
\sum_{n=0}^{N-a} {N-a\choose n} n
\int_0^1 t^{n+m-1} (1-t)^{N-n-m} \; dt
\\ = m + m {a\choose m}
\int_0^1 t^{m-1} (1-t)^{N-m}
\sum_{n=1}^{N-a} {N-a\choose n} n
\frac{t^n}{(1-t)^n} \; dt
\\ = m + (N-a) m {a\choose m}
\int_0^1 t^{m-1} (1-t)^{N-m}
\sum_{n=1}^{N-a} {N-a-1\choose n-1}
\frac{t^n}{(1-t)^n} \; dt
\\ = m + (N-a) m {a\choose m}
\int_0^1 t^{m} (1-t)^{N-m-1}
\sum_{n=1}^{N-a} {N-a-1\choose n-1}
\frac{t^{n-1}}{(1-t)^{n-1}} \; dt
\\ = m + (N-a) m {a\choose m}
\int_0^1 t^{m} (1-t)^{N-m-1}
\left(1+\frac{t}{1-t}\right)^{N-a-1}
\; dt
\\ = m + (N-a) m {a\choose m}
\int_0^1 t^{m} (1-t)^{a-m}\; dt
\\ = m + (N-a) m {a\choose m}
\mathrm{B}(m+1, a-m+1)
\\ = m + (N-a) m {a\choose m} \frac{1}{m+1} {a+1\choose m+1}^{-1}
= m + (N-a) m \frac{1}{a+1}.$$

This indeed yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[X] = m \frac{N+1}{a+1}}$$

as claimed. As a sanity check when all animals have been marked we get
$m$ marked animals after drawing $m$ individuals no matter what, which
is the correct result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your long answer! I had some difficulty understanding, especially since I'd never seen the Beta function yet, but I can follow you're answer now. However, I'm also wondering if there is a relatively simple solution for the expectation subquestion, using only basic probability, combinatorics and discrete random variables, since this question appears even before continuous random variables in my textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a random variable representing the number of animals it is necessary to capture in order to obtain $m$ marked animals, from a total population of $N$ animals, $a$ of which are marked. Then,
$$p_n = \mathbb{P}(X=n) = \frac{a}{N}\binom{a-1}{m-1}\binom{N-a}{n-m}\left/\binom{N-1}{n-1}\right.$$
for $n = m,m+1,\ldots, N-a+m$. The task is to find $\mathbb{E}(X)$.

By definition, $$\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{n=m}^{N-a+m} np_n$$

Let $X'=X-m$, $x = n-m$ and $p_x = \mathbb{P}(X'=x)$ for $x=0,1,\ldots,N-a$.

Then $p_x = p_n$ and
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X) &= \sum_{x=0}^{N-a} (x+m)p_x \\
&= m + \sum_{x=0}^{N-a} xp_x \\
&= m + \sum_{x=1}^{N-a} x \frac{a}{N}\binom{a-1}{m-1}\binom{N-a}{x}\left/\binom{N-1}{x+m-1}\right. \\
&= m + \frac{a}{N}\binom{a-1}{m-1} \sum_{x=1}^{N-a} x \binom{N-a}{x}\left/\binom{N-1}{x+m-1}\right. \\
&= m + \frac{m}{N}\binom{a}{m} \sum_{x=1}^{N-a} (N-a)\binom{N-a-1}{x-1}\left/\binom{N-1}{x+m-1}\right. \\
&= m + \frac{m(N-a)}{a+1} \sum_{x=1}^{N-a} \frac{a+1}{N} \binom{a}{m}\binom{N-a-1}{x-1}\left/\binom{N-1}{x+m-1}\right. \\
&= m + \frac{m(N-a)}{a+1} \sum_{n=m+1}^{N-(a+1)+(m+1)} \frac{a+1}{N} \binom{(a+1)-1}{(m+1)-1}\binom{N-(a+1)}{n-(m+1)}\left/\binom{N-1}{n-1}\right.
\end{align}

Let $Y$ be a random variable representing the number of animals it is necessary to capture in order to obtain $m+1$ marked animals, from a total population of $N$ animals, $a+1$ of which are marked. Then,
$$\mathbb{P}(Y=n) = \frac{a+1}{N} \binom{(a+1)-1}{(m+1)-1}\binom{N-(a+1)}{n-(m+1)}\left/\binom{N-1}{n-1}\right.$$
for $n = m+1,m+2,\ldots,N-(a+1)+(m+1)$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X) &= m + \frac{m(N-a)}{a+1} \sum_{n=m+1}^{N-(a+1)+(m+1)} \mathbb{P}(Y=n) \\
&= m + \frac{m(N-a)}{a+1} \\
&= \frac{N+1}{a+1}m
\end{align}
as required.